# Leaflet with martinez-intersection: Invalid LatLng object: (-8.39,37.08, -8.39,37.08)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, voronoi, turfjs

I have a leaflet map where I added a `FeatureCollection` with some polygons produced by the `voronoi` function of `turfjs` ([docs](https://turfjs.org/docs/#voronoi)). Now I'm trying to intersect those polygons with a `MultiPolygon` representing a country, so that the Voronoi polygons show only inside said country. For the intersection I'm using [martinez](https://github.com/w8r/martinez).

Voronoi Polygons:

```
var voronoiPolygons = turf.voronoi(poll1); //Creating the Polygons
voronoiPolygons.features.map((f, i) => {
    f.properties = poll1.features[i].properties; //Adding the original properties to the new Polygons
});
```

Intersection with the country border:

```
voronoiPolygons.features.forEach(trimBorder);

function trimBorder(value,index,array){
    //Intersection using Martinez, returns set of coordinates
    let newPolygon = martinez.intersection(value.geometry.coordinates, borderPT.geometry.coordinates);

    //Change the feature type to MultiPolygon if the intersection generates a MultiPolygon
    voronoiPolygons.features[index].geometry.coordinates = newPolygon;
    if (newPolygon.length > 1) voronoiPolygons.features[index].geometry.type = "MultiPolygon"; 
}
```

However, when I run this I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (-8.395214820999854,37.08713944100005, -8.395575540353551,37.08710300941793)
    at new D (LatLng.js:32)
    at We (GeoJSON.js:235)
    at He (GeoJSON.js:248)
    at He (GeoJSON.js:247)
    at De (GeoJSON.js:203)
    at i.addData (GeoJSON.js:117)
    at i.addData (GeoJSON.js:107)
    at initialize (GeoJSON.js:92)
    at new i (Class.js:22)
    at Object.Ke (GeoJSON.js:439)
```

From what I understand, there shouldn't be 2 sets of coordinates in that object. What's causing this?

Comment: Please share your complete code, because the error happens when you convert the intersection result to a L.GeoJSON

Comment: After the code I posted I just do ```L.geoJSON(voronoiPolygons).addTo(map);```. Well, I just fixed it by changing every Polygon to MultiPolygon. Not sure why though.